# is there Google assistance available for Arduino or Raspberry pi by this date?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi4

I am developing a smart speaker, I have the amplifier and speaker part ready but for the final step need to integrate a voice assistance in it. I have the option of using raspberry pi4 or Arduino.Also I would want to control the output pins of the boards using the voice comand if possibel to turn on and off some appliances through a Relay. Can anyone introduce me to a platform or method of achieving this please. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ESP866 wifi module to connect with Arduino Uno, you can connect it with the internet for using IFTTT and Adafruit IO. [Here](https://www.hackster.io/techmirtz/home-automation-using-google-assistant-and-adafruit-io-046067) is the project for your help.